# accessing information of inputs type radio in c# page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, input

hi everyone i am trying to get the informaion from those radio type inputs in the c# file how can i do that? i want to save the rating value in my sql database server.

here is my aspx/html code:

```
<li><fieldset class="rating">
        <legend>Please rate:</legend>
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
        <input" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
    </fieldset>
                    <asp:Button ID="Rating_btn" runat="server" Text="Rate" OnClick="Rating_btn_Click"/>
                    </li>
```

css code:

```
.rating {
    float:left;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ea0;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > label:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

thanks for the help guys!!!
i have tried to add runat=server but its destroying my style and not working

Answer (score 0):

That's because WebForms DOES NOT identify if a input is a text, check or radio, to convert it to the correct class. All elements that you use not from `<asp:something>` (or any other dir besides asp) are read as HtmlControl.
You can't use specific things in HtmlControl, like the `Checked` attibute, only generic ones.

As`input` is client-only, to read it on the code you should use the `<asp:RadioButton/>` instead.
[System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also, you **NEED** to `runat="server"`, as you are running it on server.
Maybe you'll need to review your css logic if it is changing it

Then you'll be able to use that:

```
if (star5.Checked)
{
    DoSomething()
}
```

---

Observation: Our answers depeends on "which asp.net framework" you are using to make it run. The approach for MVC would be totally different.
Please tag it as WebForms.

Also the database that you are using doesn't matter, as you are asking only about HOW TO READ THE VALUE, and not HOW TO WRITE ON DB